# Who said these Canadian quotes from WWI?

Tags: world-war-one, canada

CANADIAN quote help (just need to know who said it).

**Quote 1:** “Je ne me sentais pas vraiment canadien avant Vimy. Après j’étais canadien jusqu’au bout. On avait le sentiment qu’on ne pouvait pas perdre, qu’on était capable de gagner la guerre nous-mêmes.”

(TRANSLATION) *"I did not really feel Canadian before Vimy. After I was Canadian to the end. We had the feeling that we could not lose, that we were able to win the war ourselves."*

**Quote 2:** “Il a fallu tremper nos mouchoirs dans l’urine et ensuite couvrir nos nez. Des milliers ont souffert parce-qu’on ne savait pas comment se protéger, mais, on a gardé notre position”

(TRANSLATION) *"We had to soak our tissues in the urine and then cover our noses. Thousands have suffered because we did not know how to protect ourselves, but we kept our position."*

Comment: Can you tell us where you found these? It might help people trying to help you.

Comment: part of a project at school (high school). we are studying ww1 and canada's role in it

Comment: The teacher gave them to us. but I googled and looked around and couldnt find anything.

Comment: I found this pdf (horizon14-18.eu/wa_files/Vimy_pdf.pdf) but these quotes do not appear to be in it. You may have better luck here http://www.veterans.gc.ca/fra/remembrance/history/first-world-war/audio-archive

Comment: Might be worth looking over at the Canadian War Museum in Ottawa, I am assuming you are Canadian. Maybe you could contact them and they could give you a hand. If I remember correctly, they have a whole exhibit about Vimy Ridge.

Comment: I feel that the simplest answer is to ask your teacher. The resource that provided these quotes should really have a source that you should be able to research further. It's also possible that these quotes might be fictional (although authentic in terms of details).

Comment: Probably not fictional, but likely obscure. There have been a LOT of interviews done with war veterans (WW1 & WW2), collected locally in school and historical society projects.